# Describing event with “greatest” date value

Tags: time, comparatives, dates

I'm struggling with a way to describe one of a series of datetime values that has the greatest value.

My first thought would be to call it the "latest", but the suggests that the event is in the past, not possibly in the future.

How would you describe an event at a time which is after all previous events in the series, and can have already happened or is possibly in the future?

Comment: I would say "last" if it truly is a series in date order. And first for the one with the smallest date.

Comment: I see what you're saying, but that also suggests to me that the date was in the past. If I'm talking about a regularly scheduled event like a weekly TV show, and I said I just watched the last episode, one might think that it was the one that most recently aired, not necessarily the final episode that is scheduled.

Comment: You could go with *final*.

Comment: No (to your comment above). You could say something like "Next week's episode will be the last in the current series." or "The episode on [date] will be the last ...". If, as you suggest you were to say "I just watched the last episode", you would be using "last" incorrectly: you should have said you just watched "the latest episode" or "the most recent episode".

Comment: @raydowe sure, "I just watched the last episode" makes you think of the past, what with being in the past tense and all. And "I can't wait for the last episode" makes you think of the future. That has nothing to do with the word "last". What does "the last episode explains her powers?" make you think? Also, "a series of datetime values" sounds like a computer program, not two people chatting about tv - the latter will always be less formal and precise.

Comment: As @Hellion has suggested, you could use 'final' - but that *could* suggest the final episode *ever*, i.e. there will be no more series. But it would be OK if said as "the final episode in the current series".

Comment: @KateGregory "The last episode explains her powers" makes me unsure if it's most recent, or furthest forward scheduled. Actually, it is for a description of how a computer program will work. I guess I've always been better with those languages.

Comment: Doesn't it depend on context? Your answer may differ depending on whether the "last"ness of the date is absolute or relative. A series finale is the absolute last episode of a television show, but a season finale is only "last" relative to other episodes in that season; it's not "last" when compared to episodes in subsequent seasons. Which "last" are you looking for?

Comment: In your above comment you comment "'The last episode explains her powers' makes me unsure if it's most recent [episode]". If it were the most recent episode to have been broadcast, it would have been "The last episode ***explained*** her powers." If it's not in the past tense, it would be referring to a *future* episode, in which case it *must* be referring to the last in the series.

Comment: @longstreth I agree with you, but I'm not sure that that distinction is relevant in the context of the question.

Comment: How would I describe an event at a time which is after all previous events in the series, and can have already happened or is possibly in the future? I'd call that ***next*** – there are all the previous events, and then there's the _next_ scheduled event, which may or may not have already happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Introduction

The OP has described a scenario where there is a multiplicity of separate events on different dates, forming a series, such as multiple episodes of a television series. The series of events may be:

1. *wholly in the past*, including the distant past and/or the immediate past;
2. *straddling the past, present and future*, i.e. at least one of the events in the series is in the past, one may be in the present, and at least one is in the future;
3. *wholly in the future*, including the immediate future and/or the distant future.

The OP wants a word (or phrase) to describe the *chronologically last* event in the series  (which he describes as the event having the "greatest (or highest) date-time value"). The chosen word (or phrase) *must* be suitable for use in *all* of the situations described in 1 - 3 above.

## Choices

A number of different choices of word or phrase have been offered so far in comments and answers. These are:

> latest - last - final - next - most recent - most future - farthest (or furthest) date forward

I propose to address these separately, and look at the relevant dictionary definitions of the main contenders.

### most future - farthest (or furthest) date forward

Neither of these is suitable if the series of events is wholly in the past, because otherwise the *chronologically last* event in the series will not be in the future.

### most recent

This is suitable only if the series of events is wholly in the past, because otherwise the *chronologically last* event in the series will be in the future.

### next

This is not suitable if the whole series is in the past, or if more than one event in the series is in the future.

### last

#### Dictionary definitions:

**last *adjective***

> from [Chambers Dictionary](http://www.chambers.co.uk/search.php?query=last&title=21st)
>   1. being, coming or occurring at the end of a series or after all others.
>   2. usually applied to dates, time, etc: most recent; happening immediately before the present (week, month, year, etc).
>   [other definitions not relevant to this question]
>
> from [Oxford Dictionaries Online (ODO)](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/last?q=last)
>   1. coming after all others in time or order; final: [examples omitted]
>   2. most recent in time; latest: *last year*
>
> from [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/last)
>   1. after all others : at the end 
>   2. most lately 
>   3. in conclusion
>
> from [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/last)
>   11. after all others; latest: *He arrived last at the party.*
>   12. on the most recent occasion: *When last seen, the suspect was wearing a checked suit.*
>   13. in the end; finally; in conclusion.

[Merriam-Webster Learner's](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/search/last) and [Longman](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/last_2) add nothing additional of relevance.

#### Discussion

This was my initial first choice, and indeed the dictionaries all show it to have a primary meaning of:

> being, coming or occurring at the end of a series or after all others

which would may it eminently suitable. But it also has a secondary meaning of:

> most recent (usually applied to dates, time, etc)

which makes it ambiguous when the series straddles past, present and future, because it could refer to the last episode of the series (in the future), but it could also mean the 
"most recent" episode (in the past).

### latest

#### Dictionary definitions:

**latest *adjective***

> from [Chambers Dictionary](http://www.chambers.co.uk/search.php?query=latest&title=21st)
>   1. most recent • *the latest update on the news*.
>   2. (**the latest**) the most recent news, occurrence, fashion, etc.
>     **at the latest** not later than a specified time.

[Oxford Dictionaries Online (ODO)](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/late?q=latest), [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/latest), [Merriam-Webster Learner's](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/search/latest%5B1%5D), [Longman](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/latest_1?ModPagespeed=noscript), and [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/latest) all give *most recent* as the primary or only definition.

[Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/latest) also gives *last*, and [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/latest) gives *last (archaic)*

#### Discussion

All the dictionaries give the only relevant meaning of ***latest*** as:

> most recent

which is the same as the secondary meaning of ***last***, and implies that it *must* be referring to a past event, which would make it an unsuitable choice for the required purpose.

No dictionaries give the required meaning of "the end of a series", but two do give the meaning of "last", although one indicates that meaning to be archaic.

Nevertheless, @FumbleFingers has argued that ***latest*** can be and is used to refer to the *chronologically last* date in a series of dates falling wholly or partially in the future. He has cited references referring to the *latest expiry date*, *latest expiration date*, and *latest maturity date*.

Although I accept that those usages are appropriate, valid, and seen in legal documents, I would argue that that usage is different from the requirement here. In those cases, there is not a series of *events*: there is *one event* (expiry, maturity, etc.) but a choice of *dates* on which the *single event* can occur. The terminology there refers to the chronologically last date from the available choices of date: it does not refer to a *last event* because there is only one event.

In any case, the primary meaning of ***latest*** as "most recent" rules it out as a choice here, because of the resultant ambiguity.

### final

#### Dictionary definitions:

**final *adjective***

> from [Chambers Dictionary](http://www.chambers.co.uk/search.php?query=final&title=21st)
>   1. occurring at the end; last in a series, after all the others.
>   2. completed; finished.
>
> from [Oxford Dictionaries Online (ODO)](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/final?q=final)
>   coming at the end of a series

from [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/final)

> 1. coming at the end : being the last in a series, process, or progress

from [Merriam-Webster Learner's](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/search/final)

> 1. *always used before a noun*
>      a. happening or coming at the end

from [Longman](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/final_1)

> 1. [only before noun] last in a series of actions, events, parts of a story etc:
>      *The final episode will be shown tonight.*
>
> from [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/final?s=t)
>   1. pertaining to or coming at the end; last in place, order, or time

#### Discussion

Several dictionaries give the primary (relevant) meaning of ***final*** as:

> occurring at the end
>   last in a series of events
>   after all the others
>   last in time

This makes it not only a suitable choice, but the only remaining choice without some kind of ambiguity. There could be some minor ambiguity over whether it refers to the final episode of a 'current' series, or to the final ever episode (final episode of the final series), but that seems insignificant in the light of the problems with other choices.

## Conclusion

The most suitable choice is ***final***.

Comment: I disagree with your final conclusion. Given the list *Jan 2012, Mar 2010, Oct 2011, Dec 2000*, I would unhesitatingly identify *Dec 2000* as the "final" (and indeed, the "last") date in the list. But *Jan 2012* is undoubtedly the **latest**, since the meaning of that word is unaffected by the list order.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I accept that, and must admit that I was working on the assumption that - if we were talking about a series of episodes - the series was in date order with earliest first. The OP seems so concerned that *latest* and *last* could mean most recent. So I'm now not sure that we've come up with any word that is unambiguous and meets the OP's needs. (I still think *latest* also has the disadvantages I mentioned.)

Comment: I must admit I'm surprised several people seem to think *latest* somehow inevitably implies *in the past*. I can understand how dictionaries will tend to support that assumption, since their definitions are likely to say things like *most recent*. But in ordinary contexts we're always seeing things like *"The latest date for applications to be received is [some future date]"*. The *most recent* definition is just a convenient short form - it doesn't encapsulate the full scope of the word.

Answer (score 4):

OP is simply mistaken in thinking *latest* must imply the events are all in the past. But he's not alone - I've heard people speak of the *highest* date in computing contexts, to avoid confusion.

But here are hundreds of thousands of 1000s of instances of [**latest** expiry](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22latest%20expiry%20date%22&oq=%22latest%20expiry%20date%22&aqs=chrome.0.69i57.54274892j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) / [expiration date](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22latest%20expiry%20date%22&oq=%22latest%20expiry%20date%22&aqs=chrome.0.69i57.54274892j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#sclient=psy-ab&q=%22latest%20expiration%20date%22&oq=%22latest%20expiration%20date%22&gs_l=serp.3..0i30j0i8i30.122474.123981.0.124244.6.6.0.0.0.0.66.326.6.6.0...0.0.0..1c.1.17.psy-ab.yJ7G4_9Zzt8&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.48705608,d.d2k&fp=9082b0a7aeffa604&biw=1194&bih=899), many of which will involves future dates. That would be my preferred option.

If we suppose OP has a list of date values, I certainly wouldn't advise referring to the ***last*** date, since that might simply mean the one that comes *last in the list*, which might not be the ***latest***.

Comment: I'm not convinced you are right. All the dictionaries I looked in defined "latest" to mean "most recent", and "recent" can't be in the future. You do offer examples, but I think they are more examples of the very confusion the OP is trying to diffuse. I'd go with highest to be safe.

Comment: @Fraser Orr: There's no reason you should be forced to use a form of words you're not happy with, but I didn't really put *highest* in there as a "better" alternative - it's just that in computing contexts we often treat dates as "scalar numbers", so the usage is at least "credible". But I still think you're *still* mistaken. Here are some more written instances of [latest maturity date](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22latest+maturity+date%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), many if not most of which clearly refer to dates which haven't arrived yet at the time of writing.

Comment: Thinking about how to use "latest" to convey a future event made me realize, you are absolutely right! :) See my comment at Jim's answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would use **most recent** or *latest* (as Fumblefingers suggested) for past events.

For future events, you can consider **most future**. (As in, for example, "Tell me the most future date where you have made dinner plans.")

Comment: It is very possible to use "the latest" to talk about a future date, see my modest scenario: A: Let's meet tomorrow 11.30 in the morning. B: Sorry I can't make it for then, I've got something else lined up. A: Well, what about 12 o'clock? B: Still too early. A: So when's **the latest** you can come? B: I suppose, I could make it for 12.15. A: Better late than never!

Comment: You make a good point!

Answer (score 0):

While is is not elegant, *[farthest](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/farthest) [or furthest] date forward* would unambiguously convey what you are trying to express.

Comment: [Metaphorically](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Metaphors.pdf), anyway. This is the Time is Motion in Space metaphor theme, where life consists in travel from earlier to later; naturally, _far, distant, close, near, long, short,_ and many other terms denoting **length** (and not time) get used to represent duration of states or events.

Comment: @JohnLawler Numerous dictionaries define *farthest* to refer to time or the stage of a process, not just physical space.

Comment: That's because these are old metaphors. Real time words, like _when_ and _during_ can **only** be used for time; anything else is a metaphor. Not surprising, really; we can see distances and motion, but we haven't the foggiest notion what "time" is.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this semantic problem while working with software package.  The term I came up with was the greatest future date.  This wasn't completely satisfying, but my customer understood it.  "Farthest future date", "furthest from today"?  Not sure.

Comment: But this doesn’t work for an event in the past, and the question asks for a term or phrase that covers both cases.

Comment: Most recent or greatest future date.  Not succinct, not satisfying, but it describes it.