# "My latest five novels" or "my five latest novels"?

Tags: adjectives, word-order, numbers, determiners, superlative-degree

Is it okay to say "my latest *five* novels" when I want to express "five of my *latest* novels"?

As far as I know, "five" is a postdeterminer, so it precedes an adjective (except for "last/following/top", to name a few) as a rule.

Comment: Maybe what you want is _my **last** five novels_.

Comment: [This answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/119106/describing-event-with-greatest-date-value/119181#119181) of mine on another question compares dictionary definitions of *last* and *latest* and discusses their differences. It is not directly relevant to the current question, but may be of assistance.

Answer (score 3):

> My latest five novels

This means the last five novels that you have written: no more and no less.

> Five of my latest novels

This means that you are referring to five particular (but unspecified) novels selected from an unspecified number of your recent novels.  This has the implications that:

- You are *not* referring wholly to the five most recent novels. You might be referring, say, to the four most recent ones and one earlier one, but the combination is not specified. You might even not be including *the most recent* novel.
- Additionally, the meaning of *latest* is unspecified and cannot be inferred from your statement. Other than the fact that it is a period going back implicitly to at least six novels ago (and probably more), we do not know whether *my latest novels* goes back 1 year, 3 years, 10 novels, 20 novels, or whatever - and a judgement can be made only by looking at your recent frequency of publication.

Finally, both expressions also carry the implication that you have published 'substantially more' than five novels in total, e.g. at least ten (but that number is for the reader to guess at).

Comment: I've +1 your definition of "five of my latest novels" which had escaped my attention, but don't you think that it sounds weird to talk about *five* latest novels when the distance between each novel being written, and then published must take at least a year? Can we talk about something being latest when more than five years have passed? When we talk about the *latest news* from the Middle-East we don't think about 2011, do we?

Comment: @Mari-LouA I agree to some extent. I think "my 5 latest" is fine because it's merely comparative, even if it does go back 5 years. I did have some difficulty with time scale for "5 of my latest" - but it *does not* mean the same as "5 latest" and I tried to convey that. As regards overall time scales, not being a novelist, I have no idea but did think it would be rather longer term (and hence the expression is less useful and more vague), but I thought that some very prolific novel-writers could produce several per year?! (PS. Hope you've seen my response on Meta.)

Comment: Sorry my question is misleading. I was, and am, not sure if it is grammatically correct to say " my latest five novels". Thanks all the same, TrevorD

Comment: It's grammatically correct (depending on your intended meaning). *My five latest novels* would have the same meaning and probably be a little more common.

Answer (score 1):

This usage depends on your desired emphasis. Either grammar is acceptable. Your choice depends on whether you want to emphasize "five" or "latest," or "novels." In classical grammar "five" would be deterministic but any order is acceptable in modern usage depending on your intended meaning. A warning: Depending on context your choice of emphasis may slightly alter the perceived meaning of your statement!

Comment: And what order emphasizes what word?

Answer (score 1):

*Latest* is usually used to say *"the most recent"* or *"the newest"* as in:

> Their **latest CD** is due to be released next week.

and

> Wilbur Smith's **latest novel** is about Hector Cross and his
> determination to protect his family from an African terrorist group.

To use a number greater than two with *latest* such as **their latest five CDs** or **five of their latest CDs** seems to contradict that meaning of "most recent" and "newest" although both grammatically correct.

In my opinion, I would use the adjective, *last*, which is commonly used to talk about a period of time up to the present but can also be used to talk about a series of things made, released, published or performed up to the present day for example:

> Over the **last 10 years** we have travelled extensivley.
>
> (possible construction) **Five of Wilbur Smith's last novels** speak about XXXX
>
> **My last five novels** were published between XXX and XXX
>
> **Tom Cruise's last five movies** have been box-office flops.

(I have no idea if this last statement is factually correct. I am merely giving an example, apologies to Mr Cruise!)